# Ruby on Rails: How to keep validation errors upon redirect_to, without storing too much in the cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, render

I'm trying to use a redirect_to in my controller while still keeping the validation error flash messages. In another post on this site, the suggested answer was to use:

flash[:error] = @object.errors
redirect_to object_path

Unfortunately, if there are many errors (10 in my case), I get a ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow
error, since apparently the @object.errors object is too large to store in the cookie.

I'd really like to use redirect instead of render for other reason I have not mentioned due to their intricacy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the activerecord store instead of cookie store as the latter cannot store large objects.

**config/initializers/session_store.rb:**

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

And then

```
rake db:sessions:create db:migrate
```

That should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Store only the error messages, rather than the objects eg. `@object.errors.full_messages`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a 4kb limit on what you can store in a cookie, and when Rails converts your object into text for writing to the cookie its probably bigger than that limit.

Ruby on Rails ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow error

That way this CookieOverflow Error occurs.

The easiest way to solve this one is, you need change your session_store and don't use the cookie_store. You can use the active_record_store by example.

Here is the steps

1. Generate a migration that creates the session table

   rake db:sessions:create
2. Run the migration

   rake db:migrate
3. Modify config/initializers/session_store.rb from

   (App)::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => 'xxx'

to

(App)::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store

Once you’ve done the three steps, restart your application. Rails will now use the sessions table to store session data, 
and you won’t have the 4kb limit.